# Does each scrapy request go through middlewares?

Tags: scrapy

I have something like this in my spider:

```
def some_parse(self,response):
    # ... other code here
    for link in extracted_links:
        log.info(link)
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.some_parse, method="GET")
```

Within my custom downloader middleware, I have something like this:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    #do something
    log.info(request.url)
    request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', "some randomly selected useragent")
```

I am getting several thousands logs from some_parse while only a few hundred from process_request. Why is it so? Doesn't each and every page request go through the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

2 questions

1. Did you let your scraper finish entirely?
2. There is a change that most of URLs were duplicate and that is why did not go through middleware but show in your spider's `some_parse`

I am pretty sure your URLs were filtered due to duplicate.

Comment: And yes, I let them finish entirely.

Comment: @AayushKarki then it seems impossible that some URLs did not go through that middleware

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue. I had:

```
def some_parse(self,response): #1
    # ... other code here 
    for link in extracted_links: #2
        log.info(link) #3
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.some_parse, method="GET") #4
```

If depth limit is N and if the response belongs to the URL belonging to Nth depth, then all links it is yielding won't pass through the middleware while it has already got logged. Hence the discrepancy!

The correct way to log is:

```
    def some_parse(self,response):
        # ... other code here 
        log.info(response.url)
        for link in extracted_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.some_parse, method="GET")
```